# Solve: $P_n^m(\cos\theta_w)=0$ for $\theta_w$. Zeros of Associated Legendre Polynomial

Tags: roots, special-functions, boundary-value-problem, legendre-polynomials, transcendental-equations

I am working on boundary value problems with the [associated Legendre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_Legendre_polynomials) and have the condition that:

$$\frac{P_n^m(\cos\theta_w)}{\sin(\theta_w)}=0$$

I am trying to solve this equation for $\theta_w$ for any (positive integer) mode numbers ($n,m$).

I started by noting that the denominator is bounded as: $-1<\sin(\theta_w)<1$, and won't contribute to the roots.

This simplifies the solution that I need to solve to:

$$P_n^m(\cos\theta_w)=0.$$

I then began considering the [definitions of associated Legendre polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendrePolynomial.html) (note the chain rule when reparameterizing in terms of angles),

$$P_n^m(\cos\theta_w)=\frac{(-1)^m}{2^nn!}(1-\cos^2\theta_w)^{m/2}\left(\frac{1}{-\sin\theta_w}\right)^{m+n}\frac{d^{n+m}}{d\theta_w^{n+m}}(\cos^2\theta_w-1)^n.$$

Now the factorial terms are constants and don't affect the roots, while the $(1-\cos^2\theta_w)^{m/2}$ gives zeros for $\theta_w=0,\pi,2\pi,3\pi...$, physically this is not realizable for the physical scenario I am modeling so this can be ignored. With the same bounds on $\sin\theta$ from above the $\sin\theta$ term can be ignored too. This reduces the equation that needs to be solved to:

$$0=\frac{d^{n+m}}{d\theta_w^{n+m}}(\cos^2\theta_w-1)^n.$$

Integrating this $m+n$ times gives:

$$(\cos^2\theta-1)^n=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n-1}\frac{c_i\theta_w^{i}}{i!}$$

which is simplified to:

$$-\sin^{2n}\theta_w=\sum_{i=0}^{m+n-1}\frac{c_i(\theta_w)^{i}}{i!}.$$

Here $c_i$'s are constants of integration. I think this is a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), and am wondering if there are any analytical solutions known for this equation.

I had also looked at the definitions of associated Legendre polynomials involving hypergeometric functions, but to no avail.

An example for a specific mode with the $m=0,n=2$ gives:

$$0=\frac{P_2^0(\cos\theta_w)}{\sin(\theta_w)}=\frac{(3\cos^2\theta_w-1)}{2\sin(\theta_w)}$$

This gives the solution that $\theta_w=\cos^{-1}(1/9)$. Knowing this root, I found that the transcendental equation would have coefficients $c_1=0,c_0=4/9$, so that it reads $-\sin^{2n}\theta_w=c_0$. I'm sure if this offers any hints at generalizing to any mode numbers ($n,m$).

Comment: If $m$ and $n$ are non-negative integers and $m \leq n$ then $
\frac{{P_n^m (\cos \theta )}}{{\sin ^m \theta }}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-m$ in $\cos\theta$. I do not think there are explicit expressions for the zeros of that polynomial in general. If $m>n$ then the Legendre function is identically zero. A good reference for the Legendre functions is the DLMF: https://dlmf.nist.gov/14

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I had noticed the conditions on $m>n$ in the numerical solutions, but it is nice to find a mathematical basis for them.

Comment: In F. W. J. Olver's book Asymptotics and Special Functions, p. 469, Ex. 12.5, there is an asymptotic approximation for the $r$th zero for large $n$ and fixed non-negative $m$.

Answer (score 1):

I can't make a comment to your question because I don't have enough reputation points. Are you trying to model a biconical antenna (or perhaps any conducting conical surface)?

I've recently been looking at that particular problem myself, and I think I've convinced myself that for some arbitrary angle ($\theta_{w}$ in your case) there is no general solution. However, the Associated Legendre Functions might. If you let your order be real-valued ($P_{n}^{m} \rightarrow P_{\nu}^{m}$ for $\nu \in \mathbb{R}$), then you can likely find values of $\nu$ which work (I'm currently on this path myself).

Comment: @ wa03, yes this is for a conical resonant cavity. I have come to the conclusion that there are no analytical roots (for a generic mode) for the associated legendre polynomial and instead approximation methods need to be employed.

Comment: @user3491364 I just discovered the complex-step approximation to derivatives:

$$
  f'(x) \approx \Im \dfrac{f(x+ih)}{h} + O(h^{2})
$$

This could be used with Newton's method to find roots to find the specific values of $\nu$ so that $P_{\nu}^{m}(x) = 0$ for a fixed $x$.